# Python: iterate over a sublist

Tags: python, python-3.x, generator, slice

Generally, when you want to iterate over a portion of a list in Python, the easiest thing to do is just slice the list.

```
# Iterate over everything except the first item in a list
#
items = [1,2,3,4]
iterrange = (x for x in items[1:])
```

But the slice operator creates a new list, which is not even necessary to do in many cases.  Ideally, I'd like some kind of slicing function that creates generators, as opposed to new list objects.  Something similar to this could be accomplished by creating a generator expression that uses a `range` to return only certain portions of the list:

```
# Create a generator expression that returns everything except 
# the first item in the list
#
iterrange = (x for x, idx in zip(items, range(0, len(items))) if idx != 0)
```

But this is sort of cumbersome.  I'm wondering if there is a better, more elegant way to do this.  So, what's the easiest way to slice a list so that a generator expression is created instead of a new list object?

Comment: I could be wrong, but I suspect if [itertools](http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html#itertools.islice) couldn't find a more efficient way to do it (generally, as in islice), there may not be a way.

Comment: Note that the `len(items)` is redundant; `items[1:]` is enough to slice a list.

Comment: Generators come with their own overhead and unless you have a list with thousands of elements then creating a new list is meant to be as efficient if not more so.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Use [itertools.islice](http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html#itertools.islice):

```
import itertools

l = range(20)

for i in itertools.islice(l,10,15):
    print i

10
11
12
13
14
```

From the doc:

> Make an iterator that returns selected elements from the iterable

Comment: Please note, though, that islice's in-python implementation is not more efficient than the example in the question.

Comment: @kojiro, not sure what you mean. `islice` objects are [implemented in c](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/45cd2d816f4d/Modules/itertoolsmodule.c#l1103) in cpython.

Comment: C may be faster than Python, but the algorithmic efficiency is just as poor as the one in the question, which is what I was trying to point out in my comment to the question. Obviously, this also requires an import, FWIW. As to its readability, well, the implementation in the question could no doubt be improved. All this is to say I don't think there is *a [significantly] better, more elegant way to do this*.

Comment: @kojiro This is not true. I performed a quick timeit test showing that using a generator expression is indeed faster that recreating lists. If your commenting the second statement though, I dont really get your point. `isclice` is exactly that what the OP was looking for. A quick and clean way to get a limited generator instead of a new list. The way shown in the question is far away from a good coding style as the OP pointed out already. I think it was only meant to be understood as an example of what the OP wanted to achieve.

Comment: @kojiro: A third timeit tests shows: The method described in the question is even worser: list slice: 1.1535269123993572s ; islice: 0.87495659566315s ; range generator: 2.8627238423657673s; Times referencing to one million executions iterating from 10 to 15 (excluding) as shown in my post.

Comment: @Paranaix I think you're trying to prove something I agree with (that C is faster than Python). My point is that OP's *generator expression* is an implementation of the *same algorithm* as `islice`. It has some inefficiencies, (that `zip` expression instead of `enumerate`, for one) but it's reasonable. That said, I did some [timeits of my own](https://gist.github.com/3071880) and found that the times were not significantly different when C is out of the picture, for getting all the values. Did your `timeits` test the *python* `islice`?

Comment: @kojiro i simply measured the time required to iterate over 10,11,12,13,14 as shown above. The iterator was consequently replaced with the list slice ([10:15]); islice and the generator expression.

Answer (score 5):

Before I start, to be clear, the correct order of selecting between slicing approaches is usually:

1. **Use regular slicing** (the cost of copying all but the longest of inputs is usually not meaningful, and the code is much simpler). **If the input might not be a sliceable sequence type, convert it to one, then slice, e.g. `allbutone = list(someiterable)[1:]`. This is simpler, and for most cases, typically faster, than any other approach.**
2. **If regular slicing isn't viable** (the input isn't guaranteed to be a sequence and converting to a sequence before slicing might cause memory issues, or it's huge and the slice covers most of it, e.g. skipping the first 1000 and last 1000 elements of a 10M element `list`, so memory might be a concern), **`itertools.islice` is usually the correct solution** as it's simple enough, and the performance cost is usually unimportant.
3. **If, and only if, `islice`'s performance is unacceptably slow (it adds some overhead to producing every item, though admittedly it's quite a small amount) *and* the amount of data to be skipped is small, while the data to be included is huge (e.g. the OP's scenario of skipping a single element and keeping the rest), keep reading**

If you find yourself in case #3, you're in a scenario where `islice`'s ability to bypass initial elements (relatively) quickly isn't enough to make up for the incremental cost to produce the rest of the elements. In that case, you can improve performance by reversing your problem from *selecting* all elements *after* `n` to *discarding* all elements *before* `n`.

For this approach, you manually convert your input to an iterator, then explicitly pull out and discard `n` values, then iterate what's left in the iterator (but without the per-element overhead of `islice`). For example, for an input of `myinput = list(range(1, 10000))`, your options for selecting elements 1 through the end are:

```
# Approach 1, OP's approach, simple slice:
for x in myinput[1:]:

# Approach 2, Sebastian's approach, using itertools.islice:
for x in islice(myinput, 1, None):

# Approach 3 (my approach)
myiter = iter(myinput)  # Explicitly create iterator from input (looping does this already)
next(myiter, None) # Throw away one element, providing None default to avoid StopIteration error
for x in myiter:  # Iterate unwrapped iterator
```

If the number of elements to discard is larger, it's probably best to borrow [the `consume` recipe from the `itertools` docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools-recipes):

```
def consume(iterator, n=None):
    "Advance the iterator n-steps ahead. If n is None, consume entirely."
    # Use functions that consume iterators at C speed.
    if n is None:
        # feed the entire iterator into a zero-length deque
        collections.deque(iterator, maxlen=0)
    else:
        # advance to the empty slice starting at position n
        next(islice(iterator, n, n), None)
```

which makes the approaches generalize for skipping `n` elements to:

```
# Approach 1, OP's approach, simple slice:
for x in myinput[n:]:

# Approach 2, Sebastian's approach, using itertools.islice:
for x in islice(myinput, n, None):

# Approach 3 (my approach)
myiter = iter(myinput)  # Explicitly create iterator from input (looping does this already)
consume(myiter, n)      # Throw away n elements
# Or inlined consume as next(islice(myiter, n, n), None)
for x in myiter:        # Iterate unwrapped iterator
```

Performance-wise, this wins by a meaningful amount for most large inputs (exception: `range` itself on Python 3 is already optimized for plain slicing; plain slicing can't be beat on actual `range` objects). `ipython3` microbenchmarks (on CPython 3.6, 64 bit Linux build) illustrate this (the definition of `slurp` in the setup is just a way to make the lowest overhead approach to running out an iterable so we minimize the impact of the stuff we're not interested in):

```
>>> from itertools import islice
>>> from collections import deque
>>> %%timeit -r5 slurp = deque(maxlen=0).extend; r = list(range(10000))
... slurp(r[1:])
...
65.8 μs ± 109 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 5 runs, 10000 loops each)

>>> %%timeit -r5 slurp = deque(maxlen=0).extend; r = list(range(10000))
... slurp(islice(r, 1, None))
...
70.7 μs ± 104 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 5 runs, 10000 loops each)

>>> %%timeit -r5 slurp = deque(maxlen=0).extend; r = list(range(10000))
... ir = iter(r)
... next(islice(ir, 1, 1), None)  # Inlined consume for simplicity, but with islice wrapping to show generalized usage
... slurp(ir)
...
30.3 μs ± 64.1 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 5 runs, 10000 loops each)
```

Obviously, the extra complexity of my solution isn't usually going to be worth it, but for moderate sized inputs (10K elements in this case), the performance benefit is clear; `islice` was the worst performer (by a small amount), plain slicing was slightly better (which reinforces my point about plain slicing almost always being the best solution when you have an actual sequence), and the "convert to iterator, discard initial, use rest" approach won by a huge amount, relatively speaking (well under half the time of either of the under solutions).

That benefit won't show up for tiny inputs, because the fixed overhead of loading/calling `iter`/`next`, and especially `islice`, will outweigh the savings:

```
>>> %%timeit -r5 slurp = deque(maxlen=0).extend; r = list(range(10))
... slurp(r[1:])
...
207 ns ± 1.86 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 5 runs, 1000000 loops each)

>>> %%timeit -r5 slurp = deque(maxlen=0).extend; r = list(range(10))
... slurp(islice(r, 1, None))
...
307 ns ± 1.71 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 5 runs, 1000000 loops each)

>>> %%timeit -r5 slurp = deque(maxlen=0).extend; r = list(range(10))
... ir = iter(r)
... next(islice(ir, 1, 1), None)  # Inlined consume for simplicity, but with islice wrapping to show generalized usage
... slurp(ir)
...
518 ns ± 4.5 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 5 runs, 1000000 loops each)

>>> %%timeit -r5 slurp = deque(maxlen=0).extend; r = list(range(10))
... ir = iter(r)
... next(ir, None)  # To show fixed overhead of islice, use next without it
... slurp(ir)
...
341 ns ± 0.947 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 5 runs, 1000000 loops each)
```

but as you can see, even for 10 elements the `islice`-free approach isn't *much* worse; by 100 elements, the `islice`-free approach is faster than all competitors, and by 200 elements, the generalized `next`+`islice` beats all competitors (obviously it doesn't beat `islice`-free given the 180 ns overhead of `islice`, but that's made up for by generalizing to skipping `n` elements as a single step, rather than needing to call `next` repeatedly for skipping more than one element). Plain `islice` rarely wins in the "skip a few, keep a lot" case due to the per element overhead the wrapper exacts (it didn't clearly beat eager slicing in the microbenchmarks until around 100K elements; it's memory efficient, but CPU inefficient), and it will do even worse (relative to eager slicing) in the "skip a lot, keep a few" case.

---

#### Special case hackery for specific built-in sequences when performance is *critical*

##### Special case for most built-in sequences with `O(1)` indexing (`list`, `tuple`, `str`, etc., excluding `collections.deque`)

Burying this at the bottom, because while it's absolutely the fastest solution, it's also type-specific (won't work on arbitrary iterables) and it relies on implementation-details (specifically, the implementation of the pickling functionality for Python built-in sequences; this is *unlikely* to change, since it would break existing pickled data if support were removed, but it's not a language guarantee). If you're in a scenario where:

1. The input is a `list` (or other built-in flat sequence types with `O(1)` indexing like `tuple` or `str`, but *not* `collections.deque`, which is `O(n)` indexing)
2. The number of items to be skipped is huge
3. The number of items to be selected is *also* huge (you don't even want to pay the memory cost for the pointers a shallow copying slice would incur)

You can do a horrible, terrible thing by directly manipulating the iterator to skip the items with `O(1)` cost (where using the `consume` recipe, inlined or not, is `O(n)` in items skipped. It's essentially the same as Approach #3 above, except we abuse the design of sequence iterators to skip ahead to the index we care about:

```
# Approach 4 (my hacky, but performant, approach)
myiter = iter(myinput)  # Explicitly create iterator from input like before
myiter.__setstate__(n)  # Set n as the next index to iterate
for x in myiter:        # Iterate updated iterator
```

Timings comparing the best solution from before (using inlined-`consume`) for a larger input, to plain slicing (with associated memory cost and eager operation), to manually changing iterator position, using CPython 3.11.1 64 bit Linux build:

```
>>> from itertools import islice
>>> from collections import deque
>>> %%timeit -r5 slurp = deque(maxlen=0).extend; r = list(range(100_000_000))  # *Much* bigger input
... ir = iter(r)
... next(islice(ir, 90_000_000, 90_000_000), None)  # *Much* bigger skip
... slurp(ir)                                       # *Much* larger amount to consume
...
339 ms ± 3.1 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

>>> %%timeit -r5 slurp = deque(maxlen=0).extend; r = list(range(100_000_000))
... slurp(r[90_000_000:])
...
104 ms ± 648 μs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)

>>> %%timeit -r5 slurp = deque(maxlen=0).extend; r = list(range(100_000_000))
... ir = iter(r)
... ir.__setstate__(90_000_000)
... slurp(ir)
...
32.7 ms ± 278 μs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
```

For this "skip 90M, take 10M" scenario, plain slicing is takes about ⅓ the time of the optimized inline `consume`, and manual iterator manipulation in turn takes ⅓ the time of plain slicing (because plain slicing effectively has to do 3x the iteration work, once to copy from input to sliced copy, once to iterate it, and once to decrement references when the slice is released). If you did not wish to keep all the items after the skip threshold, slicing is likely the best solution, but you *could* wrap in `islice` at that point to pull `n` items from the pre-advanced iterator.

##### Special case for `collections.deque`

For arbitrary iterables, this obviously won't work (`dict` [and its views and iterators], `set` [and its iterator], open file objects, etc.), so inlined `consume` remains the only real option there. `collections.deque` is a special case though, as, while it does not support slicing, and its iterator doesn't support `__setstate__`, it *does* support rotation, so you could write a custom wrapper to rotate the elements you want to the front, `islice` them off, then rotate it back the slicing is complete (relies on not needing to modify the `deque` during iteration). For example:

```
def fast_islice_deque(deq, *slc):
    try:
        [stop] = slc  # Check for simple case, just islicing from beginning
    except ValueError:
        pass
    else:
        yield from islice(deq, stop)  # No need for rotation, just pull what we need

    # We need to rotate, which requires some fix-ups to indices first
    start, stop, step = slice(*slc).indices(len(deq))
    stop -= start  # Rotate takes care of start
    deq.rotate(-start)  # Move elements we care about to start with tiny amount of work
    try:
        yield from islice(deq, None, stop, step)
    finally:
        deq.rotate(start)  # Restore original ordering with tiny amount of work
```

Again, timings from CPython 3.11.1 on 64 bit Linux:

```
>>> %%timeit -r5 slurp = deque(maxlen=0).extend; r = deque(range(100_000_000))  # Same huge input, as deque
... ir = iter(r)
... next(islice(ir, 90_000_000, 90_000_000), None)
... slurp(ir)
...
368 ms ± 2.06 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

>>> %%timeit -r5 slurp = deque(maxlen=0).extend; r = deque(range(100_000_000))
... slurp(fast_islice_deque(r, 90_000_000, None))
...
245 ms ± 5.34 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

Or comparing pulling a smaller number of items after the skip:

```
>>> %%timeit -r5 slurp = deque(maxlen=0).extend; r = deque(range(100_000_000))  # Same huge input, as deque
... slurp(islice(r, 90_000_000, 90_001_000))  # Need islice to bound selection anyway, so no pre-consume
...
331 ms ± 4.43 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

>>> %%timeit -r5 slurp = deque(maxlen=0).extend; r = deque(range(100_000_000))
... slurp(fast_islice_deque(r, 90_000_000, 90_001_000))
...
19.4 ms ± 138 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```

As you can see, using `rotate` saves a decent amount of work in both cases, and it's especially helpful when you're pulling a smallish number of items. When pulling a large and unbounded number, it's not as helpful solely because the cost of pulling 10M items is significantly higher than skipping the first 90M and you pay the per-item overhead of `islice` where the inlined `consume` approach doesn't need to use it for the items you pull. But when pulling a small/bounded number, both approaches need to pay per-item `islice` overhead costs, but the `rotate`-based solution, while *technically* still `O(n)`, does *dramatically* less work (it doesn't touch any reference counts, and just has to fix up block pointers for work a fraction as complicated as `islice`ing).

Comment: Side-note: For the specific case of skipping one element, on Python 3,  `_, *allbutone = iterable` is an improvement on `allbutone = list(iterable)[1:]` when you can't be sure if `iterable` is a sequence (or if sequences other than `list` are possible, and the result must be a `list`). It doesn't scale to `n` skips though; even for constant `k` skips (e.g. 5 skips), it's kind of ugly: `_, _, _, _, _, *allbutfive = someiterable`. But I figured it was worth pointing out since it allows skipping at beginning *or* end *and* converts the rest to a `list` as a single step, which can be useful.

Comment: Thanks for the very detailed analysis! Just a note that `deque.rotate()` is not O(1) though, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63878383/why-does-the-rotate-method-of-collections-deque-have-a-linear-time-complexity

Comment: @tiho: True. Fixed. The work it does do is *dramatically* lower (by a factor of the block size, 64 on CPython, plus it doesn't need to touch element reference counts, where anything that actually performs iteration must do so) though, as the timings show.

Comment: One more way (two variations): [chunks](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=pVLBSsQwEAWP-YrcNsHu0upFCvslIiV2p3YwTWoyhdW7X-FlL_pRfo1p0u2uUATZQg6dN-_Ne8x8fPWv1FpzOHwO1Kzvvq_eG2c7jgSOrNWeY9dbR7xuFRoWsdpqDTWhNTO6g5cBEkrYAdIJaNSgqRqrjisfYca8HlzPt4knOrXXYLa53MCewOyYC5BGT8Ip8wSiyKs8j09KxhrreMXR8ATeypLx8FEeSKO6kPE_jhDuvjhyy4cE9A4NiVUROrCGcpVNLL4OGkF_SaxuB_NceXyDUC-CWKyOTjypEHN2M0_LeIgknMzOuJPTc3eJXiaZ61Prb6-x7otLvKaBcYubcU_VuGH1qEHMnv5wM_f8O3JkyoU0N8tpUo9M1zgd5fE4fwA). Small memory usage and cache-friendly.

Comment: @KellyBundy: Sure. I have yet to ever *want* the `None, None, 2` solution, but people can happily adapt it as needed. I didn't want to put too much into it for corner cases.

Comment: @KellyBundy: Ah, whoops. I wrote/tested that on a different machine (with Python), and rewrote it for here on a machine that lacked it. Omitted the `None` for the omitted `start` in the second case. Now that I'm at home I retested; that part should be fixed now.

Comment: Can always test online :-) I'm on a phone, doesn't have Python, either. Looks ok now (the lack of start=None support wasn't my point, I just happened to test with that so left it in the test case since you already do support stop=None). Anyway, what do you think of the chunking? I might write my own answer with it, but I thought you might want to include it in yours, as you seem to want to offer an answer with all options and I think it would be good to include it in your speed comparisons, as it seems faster than list slicing for large slices.

Comment: @KellyBundy: Actually, I ended up making it (I believe) fully functional by just delegating the work to `slice.indices`. I'm not sure what the chunking is getting here? Just a way of splitting the difference between "taking the whole slice" (memory expensive, but fast) and an index-based generator as in tiho's answer (memory cheap, but slow)?

Comment: Nice. A very rarely used function that probably barely anyone knows.

Comment: Did you *run* my benchmark? It's *faster* than list slicing. About twice as fast for long slices.

Comment: The one where you're willing to have an extra loop, I mean. The other one, where you get a single iterator, is still faster, but less so.

Comment: I elaborated on the chunking way in my own answer now, as I had plenty I wanted to say/show about it.

Answer (score 1):

Motivated by ShadowRanger's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53195387/12671057) with multiple efficient solutions, here's another. Working in *chunks*. In my experiments, it was up to 2.5 times faster than large list slices. And with small chunks, memory usage is low.

Here's how processing a single list slice might look like:

```py
for element in lst[start:]:
    # do something with the element
```

And how processing it in chunks might look like:

```
for i in range(start, len(lst), chunksize):
    for element in lst[i : i+chunksize]:
        # do something with the element
```

As ShadowRanger said, list slices are fast, but they take three passes: for creating, iterating, and discarding the slice. If the slice is large, that's cache-unfriendly. Roughly speaking: Let's say you have 1 MB cache and the list slice and its elements are 2 MB large. Then at the end of the first pass, the second half of the list is in cache and the first half isn't anymore. So the second pass doesn't benefit from the cache: During its first half, none of it is in cache. And during its second half, none of that is in cache, either, because its first half just replaced everything in the cache. Same with the third pass.

Now instead of creating, iterating and discarding a single large slice, let's do that in smaller chunks. **Then the second and third pass of each chunk can benefit from the chunk's data still being in cache.** That's what makes it faster.

Here's an experiment. I created a list with 16 million elements and processed it in chunks of different sizes, from tiny chunks of 16 elements all the way up to a single chunk of all 16 million elements:

```
chunk size 2^4     19.8 ± 0.6 ns / element
chunk size 2^5     13.2 ± 0.2 ns / element
chunk size 2^6     10.2 ± 0.0 ns / element
chunk size 2^7      8.9 ± 0.1 ns / element
chunk size 2^8      8.3 ± 0.2 ns / element
chunk size 2^9      7.6 ± 0.1 ns / element
chunk size 2^10     7.5 ± 0.0 ns / element
chunk size 2^11     7.4 ± 0.0 ns / element
chunk size 2^12     7.3 ± 0.1 ns / element
chunk size 2^13     7.4 ± 0.0 ns / element
chunk size 2^14     7.8 ± 0.1 ns / element
chunk size 2^15     8.4 ± 0.0 ns / element
chunk size 2^16     8.9 ± 0.1 ns / element
chunk size 2^17     9.5 ± 0.1 ns / element
chunk size 2^18    10.4 ± 0.1 ns / element
chunk size 2^19    11.3 ± 0.3 ns / element
chunk size 2^20    12.0 ± 0.1 ns / element
chunk size 2^21    12.1 ± 0.2 ns / element
chunk size 2^22    13.9 ± 0.1 ns / element
chunk size 2^23    13.8 ± 0.2 ns / element
chunk size 2^24    13.8 ± 0.1 ns / element
```

We see three things:

- Small chunks are slow, due to the chunking overhead.
- Large chunks are slow, as discussed above.
- Optimal chunk size seems to be around 2<sup>12</sup> elements.

That was with elements in the list in creation order, so elements adjacent in the list were mostly also adjacent in memory. If we shuffle them, so that adjacent elements are scattered all over the memory, things get slower and change a bit (note I only used 2 million elements here, as it got too slow):

```
chunk size 2^4     38.3 ± 0.7 ns / element
chunk size 2^5     29.5 ± 0.0 ns / element
chunk size 2^6     24.0 ± 0.4 ns / element
chunk size 2^7     21.0 ± 0.3 ns / element
chunk size 2^8     19.8 ± 0.3 ns / element
chunk size 2^9     19.6 ± 0.2 ns / element
chunk size 2^10    19.5 ± 0.3 ns / element
chunk size 2^11    19.6 ± 0.5 ns / element
chunk size 2^12    21.1 ± 0.5 ns / element
chunk size 2^13    25.4 ± 0.1 ns / element
chunk size 2^14    29.3 ± 0.5 ns / element
chunk size 2^15    33.5 ± 0.4 ns / element
chunk size 2^16    37.3 ± 0.2 ns / element
chunk size 2^17    41.1 ± 0.4 ns / element
chunk size 2^18    46.7 ± 0.2 ns / element
chunk size 2^19    48.1 ± 0.7 ns / element
chunk size 2^20    48.9 ± 0.3 ns / element
chunk size 2^21    49.0 ± 0.1 ns / element
```

Now the optimal chunk size is around 2<sup>10</sup> elements, and it was 2.5 times faster than using a single big slice of 2 million elements.

Chunk size 2<sup>10</sup> elements was good in both cases, so that's what I'd recommend. Although it depends on cache sizes, so different computers can have different optimal sizes. Also, if your objects are larger or you're actually doing something with the elements, so you also use cache for that, then a smaller chunk size could be better.

Granted, writing

```
for i in range(start, len(lst), chunksize):
    for element in lst[i : i+chunksize]:
        # do something with the element
```

is cumbersome compared to the simpler single list slice. We can write tool functions that help us, so we can write

```
for chunk in chunks(lst, start):
    for element in chunk:
        # do something with the element
```

or even:

```
for element in islice_chunked(lst, start):
    # do something with the element
```

(Note it doesn't use `itertools.islice`, I only called it that because it similarly gives you an iterator over the elements.)

Benchmark for iterating a shuffled list of 10 million elements starting at index 7 million:

```
179 ms ± 1.9 ms  use_chunks1
188 ms ± 4.6 ms  use_islice_chunked
230 ms ± 7.3 ms  use_chunks2
349 ms ± 2.0 ms  use_one_slice
459 ms ± 4.9 ms  use_islice
```

The tool functions can be extended to also support `stop` and `step` parameters. Left as exercise for the reader (or I might add it later, but the current simple ones suffice to demonstrate the technique and its benefits, and that was my main goal).

Benchmark code ([Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=fVRLbtswEF11o1MQ3oRyFUG2FykE-AZBL2AIBGMNY8ISpfBTxDVykm6yafe9Qo_R05QcypYCpRFgwJx58-bNDIc_fvUne-jU6-tPZ8Xtl7-f7oXuWiItaNt1jSGy7TttiTSN3ENG9gcuVYKYfdc0sLeyU1dUDU8OotfKFqQdHYK7xrJg1YQbdEeg5qoOGSPQHJwQzeAylltprNxfE7TAVebtNXxLEtM43ZNtzEpb_tyA2hZpDs8WVJ00xnpn4wmoz_EIdFWwosBfmiZDIupR_mC5DuC7CyBJvGJfrFNHQw08hZwekpYJ8R_amZHfwcesl8tVgWbR6QgjUpGYEo8Z8cICS5pNQgeu8J0kNDXxgF0MLyPN5xFcRUFxCgztUM-FLRaLe3mEATfxZ-Rrp8Dnf3D2ktYZqR6xPwThQ7lYRttpIKYHqHPPiREarNMqXoA8jIeFS8IffA_nfUqjXmeA-bwsyvGtfisXBxjMse6ymoTJD2Nm3qHACUEUtfofQ8t7iv-yy5gnwDnPes4T-oTOMO45xzjemBARswKvs_yw0PdQnko45Vdj-7bN2YQ9m3Zielhn72hIkrCVgfAsSrKrsEIRqsNELyg97KShYhBpA3pnyZKsYIN4vPzG76pXi3Q7UaW7clNV01skbs66c6qmYaGpNWn6QlpD_vwmZ1zuYCo3-Uqg-SYJzGxcq1UxmcGocGx5WOaQnaZXk5g2bwQOEnPe9_7RoDGI3BKPuZIP5WCOjBzhtMUuDBp6LZWll75kROSMKd4CY2l8VIe39fLG_gM)):

```
from itertools import islice, chain
from collections import deque
from timeit import default_timer as time
from random import shuffle
from statistics import mean, stdev

slurp = deque(maxlen=0).extend
lst = list(range(10_000_000))
shuffle(lst)
start = 7_000_000

def chunks(seq, start):
    chunk_size = 2**10
    for start in range(start, len(seq), chunk_size):
        yield seq[start : start+chunk_size]

def islice_chunked(seq, start):
    """Like islice(seq, start, None), but
       using list slice chunks for more speed."""
    return chain.from_iterable(chunks(seq, start))

def use_one_slice(lst, start):
    slurp(lst[start:])

def use_islice(lst, start):
    slurp(islice(lst, start, None))

def use_chunks1(lst, start):
    slurp(map(slurp, chunks(lst, start)))

def use_chunks2(lst, start):
    for chunk in chunks(lst, start):
        slurp(chunk)

def use_islice_chunked(lst, start):
    slurp(islice_chunked(lst, start))

funcs = use_one_slice, use_islice, use_chunks1, use_chunks2, use_islice_chunked

times = {f: [] for f in funcs}
def stats(f):
    ts = [t * 1e3 for t in sorted(times[f])[:3]]
    return f'{round(mean(ts))} ms ± {stdev(ts):3.1f} ms '
for _ in range(10):
    for f in funcs:
        t = time()
        f(lst, start)
        times[f].append(time() - t)
for f in sorted(funcs, key=stats):
    print(stats(f), f.__name__)
```

Code for the initial experiments ([Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=ZVPBjtMwEJU4-ivmFrub7TbtCkHEHstPRGEVNWNqkTjBnqCFql_CZS9w5xf4DP6DO2M7pCs1lyTz3jy_eZN8_zl-peNgn59_TKRv3_x59Ve7oYfD0HV4IDNYD6YfB0fQ4ucJRUTJ9GjoAuhm6ugxVB00PsKJ6Kkh48kcFpUeG5tzvcUvieIa2_Jthv1x0rpDIeaHFh7gfdN5ruz5cVuA0bBgyABs7wV6xljoI8r7HPY3hRI2sGG1gr3oPPFLxz5k4lilxAuZUgBf85tkthK-m9zITXFm2TdPHdqHjVrjE6FtheCRwU02kHM4HCf7yZtvqJKSHlwYnKcxdna1ycFeE-Ox4aSgU6WWMrXeLNxaCRECDSOesISqjgdgEEd_jlZCzF7qWZYCtSK4AwsrKPBtbIhuPGeMrYx6la5VVe7qOjY5pMlZ0NkpbEiSV-XrdaHP8PsXnOK6Ym0Xa9ZnImg-Xibcbq43U2xeJDIbvkwelhKMSLWUlkjj5vACJMNYr5tx5AXI1Ae3wLu6Eh-dsSR1FiOEkCFsP3B073bnLJ-zQpVDdsc2sUdLmUpf__wT_P8Z_gE)):

```
from collections import deque
from timeit import default_timer as time
from statistics import mean, stdev
from random import shuffle

shuffled = False

E = 21 if shuffled else 24
es = range(4, E+1)
n = 2 ** E
lst = list(range(n))
if shuffled:
    shuffle(lst)
slurp = deque(maxlen=0).extend

def run(lst, chunksize):
    for start in range(0, n, chunksize):
        slurp(lst[start : start+chunksize])

times = {e: [] for e in es}
def stats(f):
    ts = [t / n * 1e9 for t in sorted(times[f])[:3]]
    return f'{mean(ts):6.1f} ± {stdev(ts):3.1f} ns'
for _ in range(20 if shuffled else 10):
    for e in es:
        t = time()
        run(lst, 2 ** e)
        times[e].append(time() - t)
for e in es:
    print(f'chunk size 2^{e:<3}', stats(e), '/ element')
```

Answer (score 0):

Try itertools.islice:

http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html#itertools.islice

```
iterrange = itertools.islice(items, 1, None)
```

Answer (score -1):

The accepted answer using `itertools.islice` is not entirely satisfactory: yes it is easy, but `islice` has to consume the first elements of the list which can be slow if the list is huge and you start from a large index.

My recommendation is to write your own iterator:

```py
def gen_slice(my_list, *slice):
    for i in range(*slice):
        yield my_list[i]
```

Or, more concisely:

```py
gen_slice_map = lambda my_list, *slice: map(my_list.__getitem__, range(*slice))
```

See the difference in performance -- pay attention to the fact that the first one is in `ms` while the others are in `ns` (also, it turns out that the explicit `for` loop is actually very slightly faster than the `map` version, though as pointed out by @ShadowRanger in comments this is only because my example below is extracting a single example, while the `map` version is faster for larger lists):

```py
my_list = list(range(100_000_000))

%timeit list(islice(my_list, 99_000_000, 99_000_001))
400 ms ± 18.1 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

%timeit list(gen_slice(my_list, 99_000_000, 99_000_001))
409 ns ± 8.46 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000000 loops each)

%timeit list(gen_slice_map(my_list, 99_000_000, 99_000_001))
430 ns ± 6.36 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000000 loops each)
```

Comment: You say "it turns out that the explicit `for` loop is actually very slightly faster than the `map` version". That's because you chose a bad benchmark by only asking for a single item. `map` has a higher setup overhead, which (when the mapping function is a built-in implemented in C) it makes up for by have a lower per-item cost. If you ask for just one item, well, `map` is going to lose. Change your end index to say, `99_001_001` (requesting 1K items), and `map` takes roughly half the time. Side-note: There's no reason to define `gen_slice_map` with a `lambda`, that's just poor style.

Comment: Also note: In basically any scenario where `gen_slice` or `gen_slice_map` is a good idea (because the skip count is high, and the number of items to pull is low), as I said in [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53195387/364696), the correct solution is just to actually slice. The memory cost is a pointer per-item, which, for slicing 1-1000 items, is meaningless, and in exchange, it goes *dramatically* faster (benchmark `list(my_list[99_000_000:99_000_001])` and `list(my_list[99_000_000:99_001_001])`, and the timings are reliably about one-sixth to one-third that of either `gen_slice`).

Comment: @ShadowRanger thanks for pointing this out, you're very right indeed that the `map` version is faster for longer lists, so probably a better choice (I updated my post to clear this up).
Regarding slicing, I agree it's the best solution in the majority of practical cases. For what it's worth I reached this SO question while solving a coding problem where minimizing asymptotic memory usage is what matters, i.e., make it O(1) instead of O(n), more than the practical usage.

Comment: Well, you did inspire me to add the *most* efficient (if somewhat implementation-dependent) solution to my answer (using `.__setstate__` on the iterator directly, so it uses neither time nor memory), so should it come up, that's one approach you can take. :-)