# Why does the rotate() method of collections.deque have a linear time complexity?

Tags: python, python-3.x

According to [this documentation](https://wiki.python.org/moin/TimeComplexity), the `rotate` method of `collections.deque` has a linear time complexity. That is, for a `collections.deque` object `d`, `d.rotate(k)`, takes O(k) time. Why is this the case?

`collections.deque` is an implementation of a doubly linked list. Shouldn't it be possible to move the first k elements of the deque to the end of the deque just by changing a constant number of references (assuming k is no larger than n, the total number of elements in the deque)? If that is possible, `d.rotate(k)` can be done in constant time, O(1), so why isn't `d.rotate(k)` done in O(1)?

P.S. The assumption that `k <= n` is reasonable because that is the case in the most common usages.

Comment: Suppose you want to rotate by n-1. How do you get a reference to the n-1 node in order to unlink it from the list? You can't find an arbitrary node in a linked list in O(1) can you?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finding the element at position `k` in a doubly-linked list is O(k) time.

Rearranging the pointers may be constant-time, but you have to find the place where they should point first.